# Laravel relations with inherited classes

Tags: inheritance, laravel, relationships

Lets assume I've got an object `user` and a user has many `entity`.
These `entitiy`could either be a `pet`, `house`, or a `coffeeMachine`.

`house`,`pet` and `CoffeeMachine` are extending `entity`

Is there a way to get the specific classes like pet,house and CoffeeMachine without defining the relationship for each of this separately, but just in one method `entities`

If a person has now one of each objects and I want to access the `CoffeeMachine` object from my `House` Model, how would I do this? Is there a way for this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into polymorphic relations?  This is exactly what those are used for.  Once setup right, from house to coffee machine, you would simply do something similar to `$house->user->coffeeMachine`.  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Yes, I've read that, but didn't read if carefully enough. This seems like the thing I would like to do. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, if you need help setting them up, let me know!